# Creating AWS IAM users and groups for my application's users and groups to access S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I’m wanting to associate AWS IAM users and groups with users and groups defined by my application. This is NOT for my own authorization system, it's in order to segment my S3 folders and generate appropriate STS tokens for accessing S3 directly from my clients.

Is this considered a best practice, or is there an alternative?

Also, any pointers to tutorials or node.js example code for this? I'm finding this quite opaque when googling.

Comment: Have you found a better solution/alternative to this problem since then?

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, it appears [Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) is Amazon's answer to this. This may work for me, but it's a little expensive, a little overkill, and I'm a little concerned about the vendor lockin. Any other solutions still appreciated!

EDIT: In my case the number of groups is beyond the IAM system’s abilities (I was going to use groups as a way to define shared projects, so LOTS of groups). The best AWS alternative I’ve found is to enforce permissions in my own server, and generate [signed urls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) to secure direct S3 uploads and downloads. The only thing I’ll lose is the easy ability to revoke permissions for long lived URLs.